# Fastest way to compute cosine similarity in a GPU

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

So I have a huge tfidf matrix with more than a million records, I would like to find the cosine similarity of this matrix with itself. I am using colab to run the code, but I am not sure how to best make use of the gpu provided by colab.

sequentially run code -

`tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(df['categories'])`

`cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(matrix, matrix)`

Is there way we can parallelise the code using jit or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

1. try simple torch code like in this example from `sentence transformers` library: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/sentence_transformers/util.py#L31
   or just import the function.
2. consider cuml library which uses CUDA acceleration
   https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/nightly/api.html